# Codeigniter - How to access user defined function using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to call the user defined library function using ajax as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
        $("a.refresh").click(function() 
        {
            jQuery.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "application/libraries/Captcha_lib/captcha_refresh",
                success: function(res) 
                {
                    if (res)
                    {
                        jQuery("span.image").html(res);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
});
```

I'm getting the following response in firebug:

> You don't have permission to access the requested object.
>       It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

**Note:**
If i put the **captcha_refresh function** in my Login controller and pass the URL to ajax like below

> jQuery.ajax(
>               {
>                   type: "POST", 
>   url: "" + "Login/captcha_refresh", .....  });

then it is working fine. However i don't want to do it.

Here is my **captcha_refresh function**:

```
public function captcha_refresh()
{
        $values = array(
            'word' => '',
            'word_length' => 8,
            'img_path' => './hrms_assets/captcha_img/',
            'img_url' => base_url() .'hrms_assets/captcha_img/',
            'font_path' => base_url() . 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width' => '150',
            'img_height' => 50,
            'expiration' => 3600
        );
        $data = create_captcha($values);
        $this->session->userdata['captchaWord'] = $data['word'];
        echo $data['image'];
}
```

Comment: You are trying to access library directly, I think you have to call controller from your ajax and in that controller you have to call the library function.

Comment: Yes, my mistake was to call library function directly. Thanks for reply. @kishor10d

Comment: So, is it working now??

Comment: yes bro. I resolved this issue on the same day i had asked the question.

Comment: Upload your answer or upvote the answer which helps you

Comment: i have already up voted the answer that helped me.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create method in controller
2) Call Same library function captch_refresh in controller and return data from library function.
3) Send response from controller's method

Ajax Call Url:

```
// Controller Code
class Login extends MY_Controller {

public function captcha_refresh() {
   // load library
   $this->load->library('captcha_lib');
   // call library function
   echo $this->captcha_lib->captcha_refresh();
   exit(); 
}


// Make Library method
class Captcha_lib {
public function captcha_refresh(){
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $values = array(
    'word' => '',
    'word_length' => 8,
    'img_path' => './hrms_assets/captcha_img/',
    'img_url' => base_url() .'hrms_assets/captcha_img/',
    'font_path' => base_url() . 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
    'img_width' => '150',
    'img_height' => 50,
    'expiration' => 3600
    );
    $data = create_captcha($values);
    $CI->session->userdata['captchaWord'] = $data['word'];
    return $data['image'];
}
```

}

// Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.refresh").click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('login/captcha_refresh'); ?>",
    success: function(res) {
    if (res)
    {
    jQuery("span.image").html(res);
    }
    }
    });
    });
    });
```

Comment: can you please share a bit of code. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.refresh").click(function() {
               jQuery.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "<?php echo APPPATH; ?>" + "libraries/Captcha_lib/captcha_refresh",
                 success: function(res) {
                    if (res)
                    {
                      jQuery("span.image").html(res);
                    }
                 }
               });
             });
            });
```

Or Create a controller & call you library over there to execute you function.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->libraray('captcha_lib');
        echo $this->captcha_lib->captcha_refresh();
    }
}
```

After this your ajax url should be like this: `url: "<?php echo base_url('welcome/index'); ?>",`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in wrong way , your code :-

```
    jQuery.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "application/libraries/Captcha_lib/captcha_refresh",
        success: function(res) {

             .....
```

In this your URL will be like this **"http://your-site/application/libraries/Captcha_lib/captcha_refresh"** . it means you will make a request on this URL and it will give response to you only if :-

- You uses URL Rewrite to convert this into an actual URL
- This is original URL

But in your case none is true . Your actual URL is **"http://my-site/application/libraries/Captcha_lib.php"** and **captcha_refresh** is a function inside the file  **Captcha_lib.php** . So it is not going to execute by calling **Captcha_lib.php** file only . Its like that you have a file with class based but there are no **main()** function .

So better to use MVC (Model View Controller) technique. You can create a controller and load the library in the controller like this :-

```
 <?php 

 # application/controllers/HandleMe.php

 class HandleMe extends CI_Controller
 {

      function index()
      {
            $this->load->library('Captcha_lib');
            echo $this->captcha_lib->captcha_refresh();
      }
 }
```

And your javascript code should be

```
   jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/HandleMe",
    .....
```